# VirtualBox host key does not work on different keyboards

Tags: virtualbox

My Host key is Pause. When I setup Host key value I press the key and VB shows me a right key name. Seems like it can recognize the key! Then when I try to control my vm it does not work at all. When I plug another keyboard this key works on the new keyboard and still does not work on an old one. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, change the Host key to another one. Maybe something else on the Host is capturing the key before VB can get it's hands on to release it from the VM.

For eg. Change it to the right alt key

Comment: How is it possible that it catch it from one keyboard ("first"), but does not from another ("second")? And like I said, I set up this key from failing keyboard ("first").